# correctly adding to json from javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, push

hi im having trouble correctly adding to my json

here is the code.

When i console.log the string im trying to add is

```
     {"type":"#","name":"wh2xogvi","list":[{"0":"background-color"},{"1":"border"},{"2":"width"},      {"3":"height"},{"4":"margin"}],"listvalues":[{"0":"#aaa"},{"1":"2px solid #000"},{"2":"1040px"},{"3":"50px"},{"4":"0 auto"}]}
```

it is valid json

```
     var jsonltoload = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + jsonloadtostring + ")"));
     console.log(jsonltoload); // this is the console log i was talking about higher up
     fullJSON.styles.objectcss.push(jsonltoload);
```

But when i actually look at the json it is wrong ends up something like this

```
       "{\"type\":\"#\",\"name\":\"unkd42t9\",\"list\":[{\"0\":\"background-color\"},{\"1\":\"border\"},{\"2\":\"width\"},{\"3\":\"height\"},{\"4\":\"clear\"}],\"listvalues\":[{\"0\":\"#ddd\"},{\"1\":\"2px solid #000\"},{\"2\":\"100%\"},{\"3\":\"50px\"},{\"4\":\"both\"}]}",
```

the fullJSON comes from JSON.parse(json);    which comes from a file

Comment: because JSON.stringify() this will convert json data to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to confuse JSON, a *textual, language-independent* data representation, with JavaScript objects, a language-*specific* data type.

`JSON.stringify` returns a string (containing JSON), so `jsonltoload` is a string. I guess you simply want to **parse** the JSON and add the resulting object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonloadtostring);
fullJSON.styles.objectcss.push(obj);
```

Comment: They are doing the exact opposite. `JSON.stringify` converts a JavaScript value to JSON.

Comment: i guess you miss things like that when you not slept in 2 days, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON string is trying to escape the double quotes character you have added to string, resulting in the string. try to enclose the whole string with single quotes rather than double quotes